# How to create "CArray<CArray<CString>>& results" in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm an unable to create a 2D array in MFC as per the code  "CArray>& results". 
Code:

```
CArray<CArray<CString>> res;

    CArray<CString>strArray1;

    strArray1.Add(L"Ali");
    strArray1.Add(L"Ahmed");
    strArray1.Add(L"Mark");

    CArray<CString>strArray2;

    strArray2.Add(L"1");
    strArray2.Add(L"2");
    strArray2.Add(L"3");

res.Add(strArray1);
res.Add(strArray2);
```

Error after execution: 
error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

This should be done without overriding copy and equals method in CArray, instead is there any way where I wouldn't need those indirectly like some method of CArray that can be leveraged.

Comment: C2248 is a compiler error, not an execution error. What line in the above snippet does the compiler error point to?

Comment: Are MFC container classes still relevant in this day and age of C++?  You could simply use `std::vector<std::vector<CString>>`.

Comment: @andlabs - the compiler error is due to the line "res.Add(strArray1);"

Comment: The copy-constructor of the base class of `CArray` is intentionally marked as private, so you can't do what you're trying. The comment suggested by @PaulMcKenzie is the best way to go forward if you must have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature for `CArray::Add()` is

```
INT_PTR Add(ARG_TYPE newElement);
```

You'll notice that the `newElement` argument is passed by value. This means the element type must be copy-constructible, which `CObject`s are not. This isn't particularly well-documented; parts of the `CMap` documentation state that the value type of the map has to be copy-constructible, so we can assume the rest of the API was designed similarly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085257/why-disable-cobjects-copy-constructor-and-assignment) explains why `CObject`s are not copy-constructible.

So what can you do? You have several options.

- Switch to using `CArray<CArray<CString> *>` — store the inner dimension arrays as pointers instead of values; this also saves memory
- Switch to using [`CTypedPtrArray<CObjArray, CArray<CString> *>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbk3yw6.aspx), which allows you to use `CObArray` instead, and still be type-safe
- Switch to using standard C++ containers, namely `std::vector<std::vector<CString> >` as @PaulMcKenzie suggested above. `CString` is not a `CObject`, so you can use it directly. Alternatively, if you are just using `CString` as a wrapper around C strings, you can also switch to `std::string` or `std::wstring`, but only do this if you know what you are doing.
- Of course, if you need the inner dimension to be a `CArray`, you can also do `std::vector<CArray<CString> *>`. As usual, the pattern requires you to use pointers — you can't just say `std::vector<CArray<CString> >` for the same reason as above (`std::vector` requires copy-constructibility).
- Use a one-dimensional array (`CArray<CString>` or `std::vector<CString>` or whatever) of size `m * n` (where `m` is the size of the inner dimension). In that case, `arr[i][j]` in your code snippet is the same as `arr[i * m + j]`. In fact, this is what multidimensional arrays boil down to, as textbook examples on matrix multiplication in C will show. (Thanks to @IInspectable for reminding me of this one.)

Comment: Another option would be to map the 2-dimensional array onto a 1-dimensional one.

Comment: Ooh I completely forgot about that option! Thanks.

Comment: Still important to note, that mapping a 2D array onto a 1-dimensional one only works for rectangular matrices (i.e. arrays where all rows have the same number of columns). If you have a jagged array, you have to keep using an array of arrays.